# Count nGrams frequency

Tags: java, frequency, n-gram

I'm writing a java software that counts the frequency of monoGram and biGram in a list of String.
Get the nGrams String by String is not a problem, I have difficulties in counting the "exact" frequencies. What I mean is that if a biGram contains two monoGram I want to subtract the frequency of that biGram to the two frequencies of the monoGrams.

**Example**

I want to count the frequencies in this String:

```
golden credit card
```

I count the monoGrams:

```
"golden" with freq 1
"credit" with freq 1
"card" with freq 1
```

And the biGrams:

```
"golden credit" with freq 1
"credit card" with freq 1
```

Now I calculate the "exact" freq:

`"golden credit"` contains `"golden"` and `"credit"`, so I'll subtract `"golden credit"` freq from the other two:

```
goldenFreq -= 1
creditFreq -= 1
```

And the same for the other biGram `"credit card"`:

```
creditFreq -= 1
cardFreq -= 1
```

Now you can see that the monoGrams:

```
"golden" has freq 0
"credit" has freq -1
"card" has freq 0
```

And here's the real problem! I don't want that words (`"credit"` in this scenario) that are contained in two following biGrams are counted two times, so that the counting doesn't go below zero (or doesn't go below where it's supposed to go).

Comment: Instead of writing us an example can you present an MCVE example of your issue in CODE.

Comment: Also, format your narrative.

Comment: When you count bi-grams are you adding 1 to the frequency of each word in the bi-gram? if not, there should be no reason to decrease the frequency for words in the bi-gram. But, as stated previously, the question that you're asking isn't very clear - what is an "exact" frequency?

Comment: @JordanSeanor I was looking for an algorithm (pseudocode like); I didn't write any code, I'm still thinking how to implement my problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did my best in five minutes and I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: @user2674117 Yes, maybe you're right, I have to add 1 even to the words in a biGram when I'm counting its frequency; I'll think about it. A company ask my uni laboratory to write a software that counts the nGrams from a list of strings (twitter, facebook post...ecc) in that way that I described; I don't know why and I don't know how to refer to it (I thought of "exact").

Comment: @FedericoBacci. I was not referring to your English, which is perfectly fine, but to the fact that you made everything a code block.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "exact" freqency is the frequency with which a word appears as a monogram but not also as part of a bigram. If you look more carefully, you should only be subtracting 1 from the frequency of the monogram words for every occurence of that word in any bigram, not in all bigrams. Your example is a good explanation of why: the monogram word is counted only once as such, but appears twice in a bigram.

To fix this, you should have additional accumulation logic rather than in the post-processing logic. Once you have the raw monogram and bigram counts, you can not know how many overlapping bigrams a word appeared in (0, 1 or 2), so you have to check that as you go through the text. The way to do this would be something like:

```
for each word in the text:
    add to raw monogram count for word
    bigramFound = false
    if this word and previous word make a bigram:
         increment count for bigram
         bigramFound = true
    if this word and next word make a bigram:
         increment count for bigram
         bigramFound = true
    if not bigramFound:
         increment "exact" monogram count for word
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. If the bigrams are only to be counted for certain words (i.e., predefined "phrases"), then yes, a word should only be counted if it isn't part of a bigram. Of course, the original poster will have to say if this was their intent.

Comment: Agreed. My interpretation of what the OP's terminology is one of many possibilities.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Your first paragraph is perfect, I have to do what you explained in those words, but I sincerely don't understand what your pseudocode is trying to do; the boolean bigramFound it's always true and you check for its value three times.

Comment: My mistake. bigramFound is supposed to start false. Fixed.

Comment: Basically, you should check if the current word is part of a bigram and not increment the exact monogram count in that case.